# JavaScript - file upload not working on my site

Tags: javascript

I am using the exact code on JSFiddle example over [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bkzfk/89/)

Works fine on JSFiddle but will not work on my hosting site, copied it exactly. Is there a jQuery include type I am missing?
I used firebug an it shows me no errors.

My code is

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input[type='image']").click(function() {
    $("input[id='my_file']").click();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="image" src="/images/camera.png" width="30px"/>
    <input type="file" id="my_file" style="display: none;" />
</body>
```

Comment: Why don't you do it like this (without JS ?) http://jsfiddle.net/Bkzfk/90/

Comment: thank you for the very simple answer :)